# How to install a browser's extension with c++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, firefox, google-chrome

I need a way to install a firefox and chrome extension with my C++ application.

How to do that and how to avoid to install it via browser ( firefox and chrome ) ?

Comment: You need the browser to install the extension, considering it's the browser that's going to use it. You can *initiate* this install in C++, just as you would with any programming language, but it's not possible to subvert the browser entirely when installing browser extensions.

Comment: @Cody: well, in the case of Firefox all the formats for the contents of the profile directory are publicly known. So in principle you could just kill any running Firefox processes, and manipulate that directory the same way Firefox would if it installed the extension. But you're right in that it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/external_extensions.html

Firefox:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extension_Packaging

Note that you dont have to close the browser in order to install an extension.
The extension will be found the next time the browser is launched.